# Does Beautiful Soup allow for the exclusion of html code by div (or other filters)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Does Beautiful Soup allow for the exclusion of html code by div (or other filters)?

I am trying to parse code that is very poorly written, where there is not an appropriate tag, id, class or anything else to key on parsing the desired content.

What I am looking for is a select or findall everything in a id that is not a certain class. Per the sample code below, I want everything in id-main that is not contained in class-toc-indentation.

Below I have main_txt and toc_txt, though my goal is to have main_txt with toc_txt further parsed out.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_file)
    title = soup.find('title')    
    main_txt = soup.findAll(id='main')[0]
    toc_txt = soup.findAll(class_ ='toc-indentation')
```

I did my best to find the answer but just can seem to locate anything that will help me.

Please let me know if you have any questions or required further info.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be with BeautifulSoup? with lxml you can do quite specific selections by using xpath selection.

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 uses lxml if you want.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help!  so I can use lxml via Beautiful Soup without downloading lxml?

Answer (score 3):

To get all elements inside main_text except those that are inside elements with class 'toc-indentation':

```
def not_inside_toc(tag):
    return tag.get('class') != ['toc-indentation'] or tag.clear()

main_text = soup.find(id='main')
tags = main_text.find_all(not_inside_toc)
```

Comment: A full update will be provided when I am off of mobile. Thanks J.F. this looks good but I receive a syntax error at !=. Any ideas? It will be slick if it works.

Comment: syntax error might be due to Unicode whitespace (non-breakable space in particular) or quotes. Make sure there are no non-ASCII characters have appeared in the code due to copy-paste

Comment: Firstly, THANKS! Secondly, where would I put the non-ASCII conversion code? BS4 seems to have lost some decoding functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: @veblen: nowhere. I'm talking about characters in *the Python source code* itself (that might cause `SyntaxError`), not html.

Comment: Thanks! It's working though I'm still testing the output. The key is knowing that a "not" works.

Answer (score 1):

By passing a function to find_all you can make a filter doing what you want.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

```
def myFilter(tag, ID, cls):
    '''
    Returns every eleement that have a parent with id=ID and class != cls
    '''
    if tag.has_attr('class') and  cls not in tag['class']:
        parent =  tag.parents.next()
    else:
        return False
    if parent.has_attr('id') and ID in parent['id']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print soup.find_all(lambda tag: myFilter(tag, 'main', 'toc-indentation'))
```

Comment: with Xpath the xpath selction query would be //*[@id="main"]/*[@class != "toc_indentation"]

Comment: Nope, but lxml does. So if he's gonna do many such complex queries. it might be easier to  switch to that. Instead of creating these filter functions.

Comment: it doesn't support grandchildren (and further nested levels). Why do you use `tag.parents.next()` instead of `tag.parent`? Also `id` attribute has string value (not a list) and there is no point to compare substring of an `id`: either the whole string matches or not i.e., you should use `return ID == parent.get('id')` instead of the last `if/else`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Exploring bs4.element.Tag in ipython (which is the type of tag) did not reveal any .parent, but it did reveal a .parents that was a generator. Rechecking in the function for an attribute .parent reveals that you are indeed correct. I only checked the type of ['class'], assuming  type consistency was a bit optimistic, and you are correct again. Supporting further nested levels was not needed in this case i think, but you are welcome to add a new answer for further reference.

Comment: @M4rtini: [my current answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20557445/4279) supports arbitrary nesting.

Comment: @M4rtini:When off of mobile I'll do worthy update. The code is giving off an AttributeError: generator has no attribute 'next'  It occurs in myFilter: parent = tag.parents.next()     Any ideas?  This looks good!

Comment: Use J.F Sebastian's code, it should be both more robust and faster :)